# Embedding XML into HTML

Tags: html, xml

I am trying to embed XML file into HTML but it is not working.
Code I have tried:

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PrintLetterBarcodeData uid="222222222" name="ABC XYZ PQR" 
gender="M" yob="1991" co="S/O PQR" 
street="XYZ" lm="ABC" loc="PQR," 
vtc="Bk." dist="ABC" state="XYZ" pc="488888"/>
```

HTML File:

```
<html>
<body>
TEST
<xml id="mysrc" src="yoga.xml"></xml>

<table border="1" datasrc="#mysrc">
<tr>
<td><span datafld="uid"></span></td>
<td><span datafld="name"></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

It is not showing proper output.

Comment: What is "proper output"? There is no such thing as an `<xml>` tag in HTML to import data. Are you running any special server side software?

Answer (score 0):

The [`xml` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535918%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is an IE-only construct, and even IE dropped support to it (at least when used this way) in version 10. You can still use it in IE 10 and IE 11, but you must set them to simulate an older version, like IE 9. (Press F12 to enter developer tools where you can set the emulation mode.)

So you probably need a different approach, like converting an XML file into another format or using server-side techniques that read XML data and generate HTML constructs from it, or maybe XSL.